# Chrome extension execCommand('copy') not copying

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Just started on a test chrome extension, basically I want to change the link on right click and send to clipboard, see:

**background.js**

```
var convert_buylink = function(event){
    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href = event.linkUrl;
    parser.hostname = 'cart.local.co.nz';
    parser.protocol = 'http';
    var link = document.createElement('input');
    //link.value = parse.href;
    link.value = 'abc';
    link.focus();
    link.select();
    document.execCommand('SelectAll');
    document.execCommand("Copy")
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({title: "Copy Local BuyLink", contexts:["link"], onclick: convert_buylink});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Local Buylink",
  "description": "Changes buylink to local cart",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "clipboardWrite"
   ]
}
```

I have read about some results from google about the copy not working, all of them saying it doesn't work on content page, but according to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages):

> A background page will be generated by the extension system that includes each of the files listed in the scripts property.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the `input` inside a document object of the background page, which fails because the user gesture (context menu click) required for the `copy` command to work was performed in another document object: the web page. Also the element you create doesn't belong to `document` yet, it's a detached node.

Solution: create a hidden `input` inside the web page.

- background.js:

  ```js
  function convert_buylink(info, tab) {
      var parser = new URL(info.linkUrl);
      parser.hostname = 'cart.local.co.nz';
      parser.protocol = 'http';
      clipboardCopy(parser.href);
  }

  function clipboardCopy(text) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "\
          var input = document.createElement('input');\
          input.value = '" + text.replace(/'/g, "\\'") + "';\
          input.style.cssText = 'opacity:0; position:fixed';\
          document.body.appendChild(input);\
          input.focus();\
          input.select();\
          document.execCommand('Copy');\
          input.remove();\
      "});
  }
  ```
- manifest.json:

  ```js
    "permissions": [
         ..............
         "activeTab"
    ],
  ```

Comment: does your js code sit inside `background.js` or in another script file?

Comment: Yes, I would mention it otherwise. Apparently I've confused you with `Create a hidden input inside the web page`, so I've added a clarification in the answer.